# Duplicate Menu and Data in Fragments after using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I tried so many answers provided by various posts here but nothing worked for me.

**Problem-** I have navigation drawer that has 6 fragments but single activity. Everything worked fine till I changed 1st ranked fragment in drawer. I wanted Swipe tabs inside first fragment. So I used `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

- Each fragment has its own menu along with MainActivity Menu.

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Notify the system to allow an options menu for this fragment.
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }
  ```

  And inflated like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.story, menu);
  }
  ```
- Everything works fine. But When I visit other fragments in navigation drawer then it shows duplicate menu in toolbar. It creates more duplicates if there is space left in toolbar when I visit other fragments.

**Try 1** : To solve this problem I initially used:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.story, menu);
}
```

With this I don't get duplicate menu but now I don't see `MainActivity menus`.

**Try 2**:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.story, menu);
}
```

With this I get both Fragment and Activity menu but Duplicates are there.

This should be easy to solve but I am not picking up a way to deal with this. Maybe I didn't understand the life cycle well?

**My other approach**- Implementing all menus in Fragments will do the trick but this should be our last option.

**Solution to this** - To maintain both Menu all I have to do is this (Very easy solution):

```
menu.clear();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.story, menu);
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

**Problem 2** `OnOptionsItemSelected` method from 1st fragment is getting called in other fragments.

Comment: so basically you want common menu items across all fragments coming in from your activity_menu file and rest from the fragments right?

Comment: In other fragments if you don't want menu then call `setHasOptionsMenu(false);` for them.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I want menu from every fragment.

Comment: @Roon13 well then your last option is the best option.. implementing menu items[Fragment related]  + common one in all Fragments..

Comment: @Roon13 i read your question again..So, your fragment was and must be showing menu items properly prior to changing your first fragment to implement FragmentPagerAdapter,right?

Comment: Yes initially it was working fine. I used FragmentPagerAdapter inside 1st fragment for swipe views. After that this problem is started.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void hideAllMenuItems() {
        if (actionBarMenu != null) {
            actionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.action_item1).setVisible(false);
            actionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.action_item2).setVisible(false);
        }
    }


    private void showMenuIcon() {
        if (actionBarMenu != null) {
            hideAllMenuItems();
            if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment1)
                actionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.action_item1).setVisible(true);

            else if (currentFragment instanceof Fragment2)
                actionBarMenu.findItem(R.id.action_item2).setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```

call shoeMenuIcon() each time new fragment load..

Hope you are looking for this